# React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a form validation system in React as forms are being filled, like so:

**Orders.jsx**

```
import { orderFormRules } from './forms/form-rules.js';
import FormErrors from './forms/FormErrors.jsx';

class Orders extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      formClient: {
        client: '',
        phone: '',
        email: '',
        select: '',
      },
      clients:[],
      orderFormRules:orderFormRules,
      valid:false
    };
    this.handleSubmitOrder = this.handleSubmitOrder.bind(this);
    this.handleOrderFormChange = this.handleOrderFormChange.bind(this);
  };

validateForm() {
    // define self as this
    const self = this;
    // get form data
    const formClient = this.state.formClient;
    // reset all rules
    self.resetRules()
    if (self.props.formType === 'Order'){
      const formRules = self.state.orderFormRules;
      if (formClient.client.length > 5) formRules[0].valid = true;
      if (this.validateEmail(formClient.email)) formRules[1].valid = true;
      if (formClient.phone.length > 5) formRules[2].valid = true;
      if (formClient.select.length > 5) formRules[3].valid = true;
      self.setState({formClient: formRules})
      if (self.allTrue()) self.setState({valid: true});
    }
  };

allTrue() {
    let formRules = orderFormRules;
    if (this.props.formType === 'Order') {
      formRules = orderFormRules;
    }
    for (const rule of formRules) {
      if (!rule.valid) return false;
    }
    return true;
  };

  resetRules() {
    const orderFormRules = this.state.orderFormRules;
    for (const rule of orderFormRules) {
      rule.valid = false;
    }
    this.setState({orderFormRules: orderFormRules})
    this.setState({valid: false});
  };

  validateEmail(email) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
  };
```

At handle form change I call for validation, like so:

```
    handleOrderFormChange(event) {
      const obj = this.state.formClient;
      obj[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
      this.setState({ formClient:obj })
      this.validateForm(); 
   };
```

And in render call `<FormErrors`:

```
  render() {

let orderFormRules = this.state.orderFormRules; 
if (this.props.formType === 'Order') {
  orderFormRules = this.state.orderFormRules;
}

return (
  <div>
  <h1 className="title is-1">Register Order</font></h1>
  <FormErrors
        formType={this.props.formType}
        formRules={orderFormRules}
      />
  <div className="Line" /><br/>
   <form onSubmit={ (event) => this.handleSubmitOrder(event) }>
      <div className="field">
         <input
            name="client"
            className="input is-dark is-large"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Client name"
            required
            //value={this.state.formClient.client}
            onChange={this.handleOrderFormChange}
          /> 
      </div>
        <div className="field">
          <input
            name="email"
            className="input is-dark is-large"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Client email"
            required
            //value={this.state.formClient.email}
            onChange={this.handleOrderFormChange}
          />
        </div>
      <div className="field">
        <input
          name="phone"
          className="input is-dark is-large"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Client phone"
          required
          //value={this.state.formClient.phone}
          onChange={this.handleOrderFormChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="field">
        <input
          name="select"
          className="input is-dark is-large"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Coffee ordered by client"
          required
          //value={this.state.formClient.select}
          onChange={this.handleOrderFormChange}
        />
      </div>
    
      <input
        type="submit"
        className="button is-dark is-large is-fullwidth"
        value="Submit"
        //disabled={!this.state.valid}  
      />
      </form>
     </div>
     )
    };
   };
```

---

**FormErrors.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

import './FormErrors.css';

const FormErrors = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="validation-list">
        {
          props.formRules.map((rule) => {
            return <li
              className={rule.valid ? "success" : "error"} key={rule.id}>{rule.name}
            </li>
          })
        }
      </ul>
      <br/>
    </div>
  )
};

export default FormErrors;
```

**form-rules.js**

```
    export const orderFormRules = [
  {
    id: 1,
    field: 'client',
    name: 'Client real name.',
    valid: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    field: 'email',
    name: 'Email is required.',
    valid: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    field: 'phone',
    name: 'Phone is required.',
    valid: false
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    field: 'select',
    name: 'Coffee is required.',
    valid: false
  }
];
```

---

**Behaviour**

When I fill the first form using cookies (any one of them), it accepts this first item and changes it state fine, according to console.log. Then is breaks at second automatic fill, or at any one if I TYPE the item, with the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

  56 | if (self.props.formType === 'Order'){
  57 |   const formRules = self.state.orderFormRules;
> 58 |   if (formClient.client.length > 5) formRules[0].valid = true;
     | ^  59 |   if (this.validateEmail(formClient.email)) formRules[1].valid = true;
  60 |   if (formClient.phone.length > 5) formRules[2].valid = true;
  61 |   if (formClient.select.length > 5) formRules[3].valid = true;
```

full console:

```
Orders.jsx:58 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Orders.validateForm (Orders.jsx:58)
    at Orders.handleOrderFormChange (Orders.jsx:122)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:363)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:412)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:466)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:481)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:614)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:639)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:744)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:753)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:723)
    at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:770)
    at runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:916)
    at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:6171)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2422)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:6271)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6301)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:674)
    at runWithPriority$2 (react-dom.development.js:11834)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22935)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2440)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:6254)
```

---

What am I missing?

Comment: Any minimal example? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: try to log `formClient` after this line `const formClient = this.state.formClient;` to make sure it is not undefined.

Comment: you are probably missing `this` context, I would say re-write all your internal functions using arrow functions to avoid binding issues

Comment: I'm not pretty sure but I think your input name should be 'client' 

`<input
  name="client"`

Comment: The error tells you that `formClient.client` is undefined. In other words, there is no key named `client` in the `formClient` object. You should add `console.log()` calls to track down why.

Comment: @Yousaf I did it and it is defined. when I fill the form for client i see the value for client in `formClient`, but error is thrown anyway

Comment: In your **handleOrderFormChange** you are updating only "formClient", so you have to set it specifically like  `this.setState({ formClient:obj })`

Comment: @tareqaziz did this, but error persits...

Comment: @tareqaziz please refer ti edit. I put full console.log

Answer (score 0):

I just refactor your Orders class component, it works for me

orders.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { orderFormRules } from "./form-rule";
import FormErrors from "./formErrors";

class Orders extends Component {
  state = {
    formClient: {
      client: "",
      phone: "",
      email: "",
      select: ""
    },
    clients: [],
    orderFormRules: orderFormRules,
    valid: false
  };

  validateForm() {
    // define self as this
    const self = this;
    // get form data
    const formClient = this.state.formClient;
    // reset all rules
    self.resetRules();
    if (self.props.formType === "Order") {
      const formRules = self.state.orderFormRules;
      if (formClient.client.length > 5) formRules[0].valid = true;
      if (this.validateEmail(formClient.email)) formRules[1].valid = true;
      if (formClient.phone.length > 5) formRules[2].valid = true;
      if (formClient.select.length > 5) formRules[3].valid = true;
      self.setState({ formClient: formRules });
      if (self.allTrue()) self.setState({ valid: true });
    }
  }

  handleOrderFormChange = event => {
    const obj = this.state.formClient;
    obj[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ formClient: obj });
    this.validateForm();
  };

  handleSubmitOrder = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target);
  };

  allTrue() {
    let formRules = orderFormRules;
    if (this.props.formType === "Order") {
      formRules = orderFormRules;
    }
    for (const rule of formRules) {
      if (!rule.valid) return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  resetRules() {
    const orderFormRules = this.state.orderFormRules;
    for (const rule of orderFormRules) {
      rule.valid = false;
    }
    this.setState({ orderFormRules: orderFormRules });
    this.setState({ valid: false });
  }

  validateEmail(email) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
  }

  render() {
    let orderFormRules = this.state.orderFormRules;
    if (this.props.formType === "Order") {
      orderFormRules = this.state.orderFormRules;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="title is-1">Register Order</h1>
        <FormErrors formType={this.props.formType} formRules={orderFormRules} />
        <div className="Line" />
        <br />
        {/* <form onSubmit={event => this.handleSubmitOrder(event)}> */}
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmitOrder}>
          <div className="field">
            <input
              name="client"
              className="input is-dark is-large"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Client name"
              required
              //value={this.state.formClient.client}
              onChange={this.handleOrderFormChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="field">
            <input
              name="email"
              className="input is-dark is-large"
              type="email"
              placeholder="Client email"
              required
              //value={this.state.formClient.email}
              onChange={this.handleOrderFormChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="field">
            <input
              name="phone"
              className="input is-dark is-large"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Client phone"
              required
              //value={this.state.formClient.phone}
              onChange={this.handleOrderFormChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="field">
            <input
              name="select"
              className="input is-dark is-large"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Coffee ordered by client"
              required
              //value={this.state.formClient.select}
              onChange={this.handleOrderFormChange}
            />
          </div>

          <input
            type="submit"
            className="button is-dark is-large is-fullwidth"
            value="Submit"
            //disabled={!this.state.valid}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
// }

export default Orders;
```

Comment: the error lies in `validateForm()`, at `self.setState({formClient: formRules})`. if I comment this line out, it works.

Answer (score 0):

`setState()` here was the problem:

```
validateForm() {
    const self = this;
    const formClient = this.state.formClient;
    self.resetRules()
    if (self.props.formType === 'Order'){
      const formRules = self.state.orderFormRules;
      if (formClient.client.length > 5) formRules[0].valid = true;
      if (this.validateEmail(formClient.email)) formRules[1].valid = true;
      if (formClient.phone.length > 5) formRules[2].valid = true;
      if (formClient.select.length > 5) formRules[3].valid = true;
      // comment this out -----> self.setState({formClient: formRules})
      if (self.allTrue()) self.setState({valid: true});
    }
  };
```

When I removed the line, it worked.